# Texture Paint doesn't work

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, masking

I'm new to Blender and I was painting the texture of my model but I accidentally clicked on F mask brush and now I can't paint anymore. I do not know how to remove this I tried to restart Blender but it doesn't work.

[image: K]

Also when I start a new file it said that "Missing Data" something about texture slots.

[image]

edit: I have this brush selected.

[image]

edit2: the first three are of the brush I want to paint, the other three are of the F Mask brush
[image]

Comment: Your blend file might be helpful to make sure, but my theory is, that by removing the fake user (when you clicked the F-Button) the texture file got flushed. Try clicking on the dropdown that says "Add new Paint Slot". That should give you a fresh one with which you can continue to work.

Comment: When I tried this on my end just now, after unchecking the F-Button, the Stencil for the brush had been removed. So I simply re-assigned it from the Slots Tab in the Tool Palette (Press T to toggle it on/off)

Comment: yes doesn’t look easy to come back to the basic texture brush once you’ve selected the mask brush, but in the Tools tab, if you select a Stencil Image under the Missing Data message, then choose back the F TexDraw, then in the Slots tab, in the dropdwon menu, switch from Painting Mode > Image to Painting, choose a Canvas Image, and uncheck the Mask option, it works back. Don’t ask me what I’ve done though, if someone could explain all this it would be great  :)) Also, when you create an image in the UV/Image Editor, don't forget to save it (Pack as PNG if you want to save it within the file)

Answer (score 0):

In that first image, you do not show what tool you are using - cannot see the error here, other than you need to be sure you are using the correct paint tool.

Second image, you have to assign a new image texture to get a slot before you can paint - simply add one and you can begin painting so long as your canvas object has UVs.

Comment: I add a photo of the brush i have selected, but it dosen't work

Comment: Get me a closer look at the whole tab with the brush texture and brush mask settings as well

Comment: yes, took the picture. Just in any case, I leave the link of the file 
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_rgF4xvkoh-wq5X0N926i1fwQBj6HMuO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Turn off the Mask in the Slots tab - with the texture used there, it is negating any use of the brush.

Comment: thank you! it works!!